# How can I edit an animation in Unity3D

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have selected a game object in the Hierarchy with an animation component attached (not an animator but a simple animation) then I tried to open the animation window to edit it by choosing "Animation" from the "Window" menu. The problem is that the animation window is grayed out and it suggests that I create a new animation. But I just want to edit the one that I already have.

Answer (score 4):

To edit the animation, you need to select a GameObject, make sure it has an Animation component in the inspector or add it if not, assign the animation in question to the Animation list of that component, then open the animation window and select your animation. it's under the time control buttons, beside the object popup.

Source: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/205198/edit-animation-in-animation-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

I have just found out why it didn't work. Because the animation component provides a list of animations, and the first element of the list should not be empty. Meanwhile in my case the first element of the list was empty and the animation I wanted to edit was assigned to the second element of the list. That's why it didn't work.

Comment: In practice no elements of the list should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

The "Animations" tab under the "Animation" component must have 1 animation under it, including blanks. To fix this, change the "size" to 0, and the animator at the bottom will open.