# Can't see Sample tab in animation in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make an Idle animation for my player, but to make it work smoothly i need to change the samples of my animation. However I can't see the samples tab.[a screenshot of the animation tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQMbI.png)

Any solution?

Comment: Write what you have tried and give us your code in text. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Take a look at this [How can I edit an animation in Unity3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229560/how-can-i-edit-an-animation-in-unity3d)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the sample rate by clicking on the gear icon on the top right of the animation tab and selecting Show. Refer to the Image linked below.

[Image of Animation Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaKDw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try to attach Animator -component to the GameObject and add animation clip to the Animator. Then you should be able to see the animation keyframes when the GameObject is selected.